# Search by association in Rails 3 with MetaSearch

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, associations, meta-search

I'm using MetaSearch gem in my Rails 3 project.

I have two models:

```
class Company < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :city
end

class City < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :companies
end
```

I have the action in CompaniesController:

```
def index
  @search = Company.search(params[:search])
  @companies = @search.all
end
```

The action's view contains:

```
= form_for @search do |f|
  = f.label :city_id_equals
  = f.select :city_id_equals
  = f.submit 'Search'
```

I want a list with city names to be rendered and the opportunity to search the companies by city. But instead of the names and ids of the cities I have something like "City:0x00000102a20488" and the search doesn't work properly.

I think that the mistake is here: ":city_id_equals". How to make it correct?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The solution is found!

Instead of:

```
= f.label :city_id_equals
= f.select :city_id_equals
```

I should use:

```
= f.label :city_id_equals
= f.collection_select :city_id_equals, City.all, :id, :name, :include_blank => true
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure your question is really clear.

First of all, I'm guessing you have something like `<City:0x00000102a20488>`, which is the string representation of a ruby object. If you want to display the name of the city, `city.name` should make the trick (assuming you have a name member on the city!).

For the search, I don't really get what you are trying to do. What is `:city_id_equals` supposed to mean to you?

Comment: As I sad, I want to search the companies which belongs to selected city. A read the documentation of MetaSearch gem here: [link](http://metautonomo.us/projects/metasearch/), and there is the example of the field with association: "f.text_field :developers_notes_note_contains". I want something like this but with a select tag instead of text_field.